# Calling a function by its name

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Sometimes we need to call a function by its name. I can do it in plain JavaScript as below:

```
global=this
function add(a,b){return a+b}
global['add'](1,2)
```

Which works as expected and `add()` gets called.

Equivalent CoffeeScript code might can be written as below.

```
global=@
add=(a,b)->a+b
global['add'](1,2)
```

which compiles to JavaScript as:

```
(function() {
  var add, global;
  global = this;
  add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };
  global['add'](1, 2);
}).call(this);
```

...and it doesn't work.

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Note:

1. I am not running the code in a browser therefore there is no window object. But in plain JS I can always capture the global scope by assigning `global=this` and then get the function pointer from it.
2. One solution in CoffeeScript I found is by declaring all functions as member of a global object like `global.add=[function definition]`. But then I have to normally call the function as `global.add()`. And it's more boiler plate than necessary.

Is there a simple hack? Or any simpler solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `add` is a local variable. Use

```
@add=(a,b)->a+b
```

to attach it to the `global` object. Since `global` is the global scope of your script you can still call `add` without prefixing it with `global.`.

Comment: This answer is correct. When you write `x=y` in CoffeeScript, you're always either making a `var x` declaration or referring to an existing `var x` declaration in the same file. Omitting `var` to create globals is widely considered a bad practice in the JS world; CoffeeScript enforces this convention.

Answer (score 0):

By default the CoffeeScript compiler wraps every file in a closure scope, but you can disable this behavior by adding the --bare switch as compiler option.

add.coffee:

```
add = (a,b) -> a+b
```

When you run: `coffee --compile add.coffee`

That will produce:

```
(function() {
  var add;
  add = function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
  };
}).call(this);
```

Now try run it with the --bare switch
`coffee --bare --compile add.coffee`

That will produce:

```
var add;
add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};
```

Now you file is not closure scoped, and you can do it the way you did it before.