# Calling a plain JS function once converted to CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In my Rails app I have some plain old JS:

```
    function reorder(divid,url) {
        jQuery(divid).sortable({
          axis: 'y',
          dropOnEmpty: false,
          handle: '.drag',
          cursor: 'crosshair',
          items: 'li',
          opacity: 0.4,
          scroll: true,
          update: function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              data: jQuery(divid).sortable('serialize'),
              dataType: 'script',
              url: url)
          }
        });
    }
```

and it works when I call:

```
     reorder("#pages","<%= changeorder_pages_path %>");
```

So I decided to convert my function to CoffeeScript which gave me this:

```
(function() {
  var reorder;

  reorder = function(divid, url) {
    return jQuery("#pages").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      dropOnEmpty: false,
      handle: ".drag",
      cursor: "crosshair",
      items: "li",
      opacity: 0.4,
      scroll: true,
      update: function() {
        return jQuery.ajax({
          type: "post",
          data: jQuery("#pages").sortable("serialize"),
          dataType: "script",
          complete: function(request) {
            return jQuery("#pGESs").effect("highlight");
          },
          url: "/pages/changeorder"
        });
      }
    });
  };

}).call(this);
```

but my call doesn't work any more - I get the Firebug error:

```
reorder is not defined
```

So to my question - how do I call the function now it is CoffeeScripted?

I have read this: [Calling a function by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506112/coffeescript-call-a-function-by-its-name)

But I have no idea what they are talking about. I have never used global=this and have no idea what it does or why I would want to use it.

I read this as well: http://elegantcode.com/2011/06/30/exploring-coffeescript-part-2-variables-and-functions/

As well as this: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1834699

I realise that CoffeeScript is protecting me from global variables and making my code better - but I can't find an explanation as how to call functions.

I have played with the CoffeeScript web site and played with the cube function - so I should just be able to call the function name I think.

I'm asking the question because I have a gap in my knowledge - any help filling that gap will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your CoffeeScript doesn't look like CoffeeScript at all.

Comment: No compilation errors, indented as it should be and it now works after following your advice below ...

Comment: Still, the code you include isn't coffeescript but the code generated from the CoffeeScript compiler

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Can't find variable" error with Rails 3.1 and Coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089992/cant-find-variable-error-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript doesn't create globals by default, and it seems as if you are trying to access a `reorder` outside the file it was defined in.

However you can explicitly put something in the global namespace by writing

```
window.reorder = reorder
```

Comment: Thanks very much. All working now. I went for a walk and hit me that it was locally defined as it was wrapped in an anonymous function. I'm not sure I would have worked out the "window." bit - really helpful so once again, thanks.